# Why setMaxBatchSize() is not useful for larger MTU in RxAndroidBle?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, rxandroidble

I want to transmit data to device through BLE. The num of bytes is 64 per transmission.

Now the problem is that, When I modify the MTU through setMaxBatchSize(ex 64), mRxBleConnection.getMtu() returns the default MTU (23).

```
    private void connect(RxBleDevice rxBleDevice){

         connectionObservable = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
                .subscribe(rxBleConnection -> {

                    mRxBleConnection = rxBleConnection;
                    rxBleConnection.setupNotification(MainActivity.MY_UUID);
                    longWrite();

                });


    }
    private void longWrite(){
           mRxBleConnection.setupNotification(MainActivity.MY_UUID)
                .flatMap(ob -> ob.merge(
                        mRxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
                                .setCharacteristicUuid(MainActivity.MY_UUID)
                                .setBytes(HexString.hexToBytes(writeData))
                                .setMaxBatchSize(64)
                                .build(),ob)
                )

        .subscribe(bytes -> {
            Log.i(TAG,mRxBleConnection.getMtu());

            doResponse(HexString.bytesToHex(bytes));

        },throwable -> {

        });
    }
```

2. Try another way **RxBleConnection.requestMtu(int)**

```
Disposable writeSubscription = mRxBleConnection.requestMtu(176)
                .subscribe(
                        integer -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "longWrite: "+integer);
                        },
                        throwable ->{

                        }

                );
```

the log

```
04-22 16:30:58.895 9435-9494/com.example.write D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
04-22 16:30:59.642 9435-9494/com.example.write D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=50:8C:B1:6A:F9:34
04-22 16:30:59.671 9435-9532/com.example.write D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: 50:8C:B1:6A:F9:34 mtu: 176
04-22 16:31:00.035 9435-9494/com.example.write D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=50:8C:B1:6A:F9:34 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
04-22 16:31:00.347 9435-9494/com.example.write D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=50:8C:B1:6A:F9:34 mtu=23 status=0
```

The mtu always be 23.

**SLOVED**----------**CLOSED**

I found BLE version of bluetooth device is 4.0, which is too low to support settings MTU. Even if the phone supports it，the device that communicates with the phone does not support it. 
Setting MTU Requires mobile phone and device support at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question from the topic — see below

`LongWriteOperationBuilder.setMaxBatchSize()` Javadoc:

```
/**
* Setter for a maximum size of a byte array that may be write at once
* If this is not specified - the default value of the connection's MTU is used
*
* @param maxBatchSize the maximum size of a byte array to write at once
* @return the LongWriteOperationBuilder
*/
```

If `.setMaxBatchSize()` is not specified the value derived from MTU is used. It is one way implication. It does not say that setting this property changes MTU.

Additionally as you tried to set different MTU you could see in the logs that the new value was not accepted — the peripheral you want to communicate does not allow it.

Comment: The peripheral allow it because IOS could send 64 bytes data to device successfully.

Comment: Logs clearly state that the MTU used is 23. There must be something that you do not mention — if there is some protocol on to of BLE to communicate using multiple packets per command or your peripheral supports prepared writes (which do not seem to be the case). First of all — why do you use `LongWriteOperationBuilder`?

Comment: The reason for using LongWriteOperationBuilder is to reduce time, when app need to send update data to device.

Comment: I use two android phone to connect, then requestMTU successfully. So it should be the problem about BLE device。But iOS can send 64 byte to BLE device successfully, perhaps because it is auto.

Comment: It all depends on how the transfer is implemented/supported by the peripheral. MTU does not necessarily has to be larger than 23 bytes to write 64 bytes — see [prepared/queued write](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_cc2640r2_sdk_1_40_00_45/docs/blestack/ble_user_guide/html/ble-stack-3.x/gatt.html#queued-writes) for instance. I can only guess with the current info.